# rand() Function Does not Work as Expected in C

Tags: c

I'm using the `rand` function in my program in a for loop but it generates the same number all time.

```
for(a=0, a<10; a++){
  srand(3);
  int sleep = (rand() % 400) + 500;

}
```

It always generates 683 or something like that. What's the reason? How can I fix that?

Answer (score 3):

Use the call of the function srand before the loop like for example

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

//...

srand( ( unsigned int )time( NULL ) );

for(a=0, a<10; a++){
  int sleep = (rand() % 400) + 500;
  //...
}
```

Otherwise you will get the same values according to the call `srand( 3 );` because "if srand is then called with the
same seed value, the sequence of pseudo-random numbers shall be repeated." (the C Standard, 7.22.2.2 The srand function).

Comment: @AlokSinghal It is now much more correct. Thank you for improving your answer, Vlad.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `srand` from inside of your loop. Each time you call it, you are setting the seed that is used to generate random numbers.

Move it outside of your loop as such:

```c
srand(3);

for(a=0, a<10; a++){
  int sleep = (rand() % 400) + 500;
}
```

Additionally, each time you run your program, it will generate the same sequence of numbers. If you wish to avoid that, you'll need to pick a different seed for each run. Typically this is a number that changes each time, such as time of day in seconds or something more unique.

```c
srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
```